# How does Vulkan's memory domain operation work

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

I read some code example about copying images between cpu&gpu using VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT. (For simplicity I'll use phsuedo code below)
For gpu->cpu It is like:
1.vkCmdCopyImage(..., src_img, ... dst_img, ...);
2.vkCmdPipelineBarrier(...,VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT,...);

For cpu->gpu it is like:

1. vkCmdPipelineBarrier(...,VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT,...);
2. vkCmdCopyImage(..., src_img, ... dst_img, ...);

I can understand the cpu->gpu part, as we need to use the barrier to make the src_img visible to gpu, so we do the barrier first, then copy src_img to dst_img. But for gpu->cpu, it does the copy first and then the barrier later. I wonder without using the barrier to make the src_img visible to the host first, how can the image copy succeed? FYI, the code example is from here, https://cpp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0xf064d23ec4332e7951809e5112a592758b3c2c71a4560a9e77da0176b1a9193a Please refer to function CopyToImage and function CopyFromImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder without using the barrier to make the src_img visible to the host first, how can the image copy succeed?

Because the host isn't reading the *source* image; it's reading the destination image, the one being copied *to*. The copy command is reading the source image, since the copy command is the one copying the image.

---

> the dest image is in the host memory

No, it is in *device* memory. You know that because the memory is encapsulated via a `VkDeviceMemory` object, was allocated via device memory allocation commands, and will be freed by a device memory deallocation command.

This particular allocation of memory is shared with the host, but it *belongs* to the device.

The copy operation is a device operation. The barrier exposes the *results* of that operation to the host.

Comment: Thanks Nicol, for the gpu->cpu case, the source image is in the device memory, and the dest image is in the host memory, without using the barrier to make the device memory visible to the host first, won't the copy command fail?(as the src img in device memory hasn't been at this point made visible/available to host memory yet?)

Comment: In many cases device memory _cannot_ be visible on the host - that's why you need a transfer operation in the first place. You seem to be assuming that the transfer is implemented by the host (CPU), but there is no reason that needs to be true (could be DMA engine, etc).

Comment: thanks @solidpixel, if the transfer already has happened, why after that do we still need a barrier to form the device domain -> host domain operation? (i.e. vkCmdPipelineBarrier(...,VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT,...);)

Comment: ... because without the barrier you have no guarantee that the copy has actually finished. The command stream defines when operations _start_, but the actual processing is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks @solidpixel. I get what you mean, your point is about the availability and visiblity operations mentioned in https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#memory-model-vulkan-availability-visibility
But in this link it also contains another type of operation called "memory domain operation", it says "If the destination access mask includes VK_ACCESS_HOST_READ_BIT or VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT, then the dependency includes a memory domain operation from device domain to host domain." are you familiar with this concept?

Comment: @NicolBolas Ah "the destination image is in device memory" this will make it make sense now! But how come?! I thought host_visible means the memory block is in the host memory and device_local means the block is in the device memory? If not, for host_visible does it mean the same content has two memory copies with one in the host memory and the other in the device memory?

Comment: @AnningWuwang: Through a window, you have some visibility of someone's house. That doesn't make it *your house*. The same goes for memory; the fact that the host can see it doesn't make it the *host's* memory. It's the device's memory, but the host can sometimes play with it.

Comment: @NicolBolas regarding where the host visible memory is can you take a look at page 10 at https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/2018-vulkan-devday/03-Memory.pdf and provide a clarification please? As it seems to show the host_visible is in the host memory instead of the device memory?

Comment: @NicolBolas And page 13 also says the host_visible is in system memory

Comment: @AnningWuwang: Vulkan is an abstraction, as are the concepts of "device memory" and "host-visibility". "Device memory" means memory that the device can directly access. Such memory is encapsulated by `VkDeviceMemory` objects. "Host-visible" memory is device memory that is accessible by the host if they so desire. "System memory" is not a Vulkan concept; it's a concept for a particular piece of hardware. An integrated GPU's device memory is always "system memory" and is always "host-visible". But that doesn't stop it from being "device memory" and even DEVICE_LOCAL.

Comment: @NicolBolas Fully understood! Thank you so much for your fantastic explanation! Is it possible to give you some more reputation points for this thread? :) I kind of remember I could give my points out in the past, but I don't seem to see any button now.

Comment: So if the dest image doesn't have the coherent bit set, do I still need to call vkinvalidatemamppedmemoryranges... to make the dest image visible to host, since the barrier should have already made the dest image visible to host?

Comment: Barrier doesn't make it visible, it makes sure that it is available. If the memory allocation is is cached on the host then you will still need `vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges()` - CPU cache coherency is independent of the command transfer.

Comment: Thanks @solidpixel, if you take a look at https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#memory-model-vulkan-availability-visibility
you will see that the memory dependency(barrier) will generate both an availability operation for the source scope and a visibility operation for the destination scope

Comment: @AnningWuwang: OK, please stop treating Stack Overflow like it's a forum where you get to keep tunneling down and down further and further into ever more specific esoterica. If you have a question about what you have to do to access memory from the host, ask that. Or just keep reading in the very link you posted, because it's right there, 4 paragraphs down.